# Error while parse a json object as ruby object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My question is the next:

When i try parse a json params with `'json'` gem on RUBY ON RAILS 3 throw this error:

```
 Unexpected token at
```

Example

I have this object in ruby:

Then I have this html code:

```
<script>
        $("#selected").live('click', function(){
            jQuery.ajax({url: '<%= deselect_all_checkboxes_path %>', data: {contacts: '<%= contacts.to_json %>'}});
        });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="selected" value="1" >
```

I try this code in Rails Console

```
JSON.parse(json_string.gsub(/&quot;/, "\""))
```

Works ok. However when i try this code:

```
JSON.parse(params[:contacts].gsub(/&quot;/, "\""))
```

There is a problem in the gsub method. In Rails Console works ok but when i am debugging throw the error message. The problem is with ";" character.

Which could be the error?

Comment: what is producing the &quot version?

Comment: @jaydel I am using rails so I convert to json inside a jQuery function. Now i edit and post the js function.

Comment: How about using CGI.unescapeHTML instead of gsub?

Comment: @Nick are the master of code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user751132 Please accept an answer if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unescape the HTML first and then parse it as straight JSON:

```
JSON.parse(CGI.unescapeHTML(params[:contacts]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to quote your `contacts.to_json` value inside your jQuery, that turns it into a string when you want it to be a JavaScript object literal; once your data is a string, it will end up HTML encoded by ERB and you get the mess you're seeing. Try this in your jQuery:

```
data: {contacts: <%= contacts.to_json.html_safe %>}
```

That should get you a nice JavaScript object literal in your jQuery and that will be serialized into a JSON object (rather than a JSON string) when it is sent back to your server.